# Invalid Byte Sequence in UTF-? using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, encode

I am receiving a file which is tab delimited and opens with the default character set of "Unicode". It's my understanding that "Unicode" is probably referring to UTF-16.

When I try and open this file using this command:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t", :headers => true) do |column|
    puts column[0]
end
```

I get the following error:

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

I know if I open this file up and save it as "UTF-8" it will work fine, but I can't manually open the file and do that each time. How can I get around this error?

EDIT:

When passing in : `encoding: 'UTF-16BE'` per stefans request below, I receive this:

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-16BE`

Perhaps I'm passing in the wrong encoding option?

EDIT2:

When passing in `:encoding => 'ISO-8859-1'`, I get this error:

`Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`

Line 1 in my file is as follows:

```
"Status"    "Internal ID"   "Language"  "Created At"    "Updated At"    "IP Address"    "Location"  "Username"  "GET Variables" "Referrer"  "Number of Saves"   "Weighted Score"    "Completion Time"   "Invite Code"   "Invite Email"  "Invite Name"   "Invite: branchid"  "Invite: lastname"  "Invite: clientname"    "Invite: membershipid"  "Invite: clientid"  "Invite: dateofbirth"   "Invite: membershiptype"    "Invite: branch"    "Invite: unitid"    "Invite: shortname" "Invite: changedatetime"    "Invite: homephone" "Collector"
```

I tried putting in a `quote_char` but I get the same error. My code now looks like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t", :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :quote_char => '"', :headers => true) do |column|
    puts column[0]
end
```

Comment: You can pass an `:encoding` parameter, e.g. `encoding: 'UTF-16BE'`

Comment: `UTF-16BE` was just an example, you have to pass the correct encoding.

Comment: Specifically as you have mentioned, you probably would use the encoding: 'UTF-8' in your file.

Comment: I get `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)` when passing in `UTF-8`...is it possible that the issue is something other than an encoding error?

Comment: The source file may well be encoded in something like 'ISO-8859-1' - try that as it is very common encoding, but if it doesn't work take a closer look at the file and find the line that Ruby doesn't like - paste it into the question, plus see if you can fetch relevant bytes for accented or unusual characters, paste them too - someone might be able to help you identify the correct encoding.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for the tip. I think that encoding format worked, but it presents me with a new error. See my edits above.

Comment: I have moved this question to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350213/illegal-quoting-in-line-1-using-ruby-csv

as the issue seems to be no longer relative to the Invalid Byte Sequence error.