# Illegal quoting in line 1 using Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I am getting this error:

`Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`

Line 1 in my file is as follows:

```
"Status"    "Internal ID"   "Language"  "Created At"    "Updated At"    "IP Address"    "Location"  "Username"  "GET Variables" "Referrer"  "Number of Saves"   "Weighted Score"    "Completion Time"   "Invite Code"   "Invite Email"  "Invite Name"   "Invite: branchid"  "Invite: lastname"  "Invite: clientname"    "Invite: membershipid"  "Invite: clientid"  "Invite: dateofbirth"   "Invite: membershiptype"    "Invite: branch"    "Invite: unitid"    "Invite: shortname" "Invite: changedatetime"    "Invite: homephone" "Collector"
```

My code looks like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t", :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :headers => true) do |column|
    puts column[0]
end
```

Since I have no control over the csv file, I would like a solution that doesn't involve me opening the file and saving it in another format.

EDIT:

Binary encoding of my file is below:

```
"\xFF\xFES\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00s\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00I\x00D\x00\t\x00L\x00a\x00n\x00g\x00u\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00\t\x00C\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00A\x00t\x00\t\x00U\x00p\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00A\x00t\x00\t\x00I\x00P\x00 \x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00\t\x00L\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\t\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00G\x00E\x00T\x00 \x00V\x00a\x00r\x00i\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00s\x00\t\x00R\x00e\x00f\x00e\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00r\x00\t\x00N\x00u\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00S\x00a\x00v\x00e\x00s\x00\t\x00W\x00e\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00S\x00c\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\t\x00C\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00T\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00C\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00E\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00b\x00r\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00i\x00d\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00l\x00a\x00s\x00t\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00h\x00i\x00p\x00i\x00d\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00i\x00d\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00d\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00o\x00f\x00b\x00i\x00r\x00t\x00h\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00h\x00i\x00p\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00b\x00r\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00u\x00n\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00d\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00s\x00h\x00o\x00r\x00t\x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00c\x00h\x00a\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00\t\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00 \x00h\x00o\x00m\x00e\x00p\x00h\x00o\x00n\x00e\x00\t\x00C\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00e\x00c\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00A\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00c\x00u\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00M\x00C\x00A\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00P\x00i\x00e\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00b\x00r\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00c\x00u\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00 \x00a\x00f\x00f\x00e\x00c\x00t\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00,\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00 \x00f\x00a\x00m\x00i\x00l\x00y\x00,\x00 \x00o\x00r\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00N\x00P\x00S\x00S\x00c\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\t\x00C\x00o\x00m\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00a\x00s\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00Y\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00f\x00f\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00s\x00u\x00p\x00p\x00o\x00r\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x00r\x00e\x00a\x00c\x00h\x00i\x00n\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00h\x00a\x00v\x00e\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00b\x00e\x00e\x00n\x00 \x00s\x00u\x00p\x00p\x00o\x00r\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00D\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00f\x00e\x00e\x00l\x00 \x00l\x00i\x00k\x00e\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00a\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00n\x00n\x00e\x00c\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00o\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00,\x00 \x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00t\x00e\x00n\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00e\x00n\x00 \x00w\x00a\x00s\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00l\x00a\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00w\x00e\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00t\x00s\x00,\x00 \x00e\x00x\x00e\x00r\x00c\x00i\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00e\x00q\x00u\x00i\x00p\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00p\x00o\x00o\x00l\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00B\x00a\x00s\x00k\x00e\x00t\x00b\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00W\x00a\x00l\x00k\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00t\x00r\x00a\x00c\x00k\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00T\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00T\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00c\x00h\x00i\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00o\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00 \x00o\x00r\x00 \x00p\x00r\x00o\x00g\x00r\x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00 \x00o\x00r\x00 \x00p\x00r\x00o\x00g\x00r\x00a\x00m\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00i\x00c\x00i\x00p\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00?\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00v\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00 \x00[\x00W\x00h\x00i\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00 \x00o\x00r\x00 \x00p\x00r\x00o\x00g\x00r\x00a\x00m\x00 \x00d\x00i\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00i\x00c\x00i\x00p\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00?\x00]\x00 \x00[\x00t\x00e\x00x\x00t\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00u\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00r\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00q\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00t\x00y\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00p\x00r\x00o\x00g\x00r\x00a\x00m\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00u\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00r\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00q\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00t\x00y\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00e\x00a\x00n\x00l\x00i\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00t\x00e\x00o\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00a\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00r\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00i\x00v\x00e\x00 \x00w\x00a\x00s\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00f\x00f\x00 \x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00C\x00a\x00n\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00g\x00i\x00v\x00e\x00 \x00a\x00n\x00 \x00e\x00x\x00a\x00m\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00h\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00f\x00f\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00H\x00o\x00w\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00u\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00f\x00f\x00 \x00h\x00a\x00v\x00e\x00 \x00b\x00e\x00e\x00n\x00 \x00m\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00h\x00e\x00l\x00p\x00f\x00u\x00l\x00?\x00<\x00/\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00D\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00h\x00a\x00v\x00e\x00 \x00a\x00n\x00y\x00 \x00o\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00s\x00 \x00a\x00b\x00o\x00u\x00t\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00 \x00Y\x00 \x00e\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x005\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x006\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x007\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x008\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x009\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x001\x000\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x001\x001\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x001\x002\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x001\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x002\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x003\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x004\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x005\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x006\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x007\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x008\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x009\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00u\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00y\x00 \x00v\x00i\x00s\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00Y\x00?\x00 \x00[\x001\x000\x00 \x00p\x00m\x00]\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00 \x00g\x00e\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00\"\x00 \x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00 \x00a\x00g\x00e\x00 \x00g\x00r\x00o\x00u\x00p\x00?\x00\"\x00\t\x00W\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00y\x00o\x00u\x00r\x00 \x00c\x00u\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00h\x00i\x00p\x00 \x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00?\x00\n"
```

Comment: Are you sure all the delimiters really tabs?

Comment: The posted line doesn't have any tabs.

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what the problem is, based on your sample "CSV", which, without commas between fields has to be something like TSV. Currently the field delimiter is a series of spaces, which could have been converted from tabs to spaces by your editor, or by pasting it into Stack Overflow. Please confirm what the field-separator value is.

Comment: I know that if I open this file up in OpenOffice with the encoding of "Unicode" and the Delimiter set to "Tab" it opens in the correct format. From the source I am receiving the CSV file from :

"Files are excel compatiable (UTF-16, tab-separated)".

I don't understand why I get an error when passing in `encoding: 'UTF-16BE'`. None of this really makes any sense, I'm sure it's just something small that I'm missing...

Comment: Is there anyway to open the file, convert it to UTF-8, and save it within my code? If I do that manually the file opens just fine...

Comment: Maybe the file isn't UTF-16BE? Maybe it's UTF-16LE?

Comment: Could you paste the first line in binary encoding? `File.new('yourfile.csv', 'rb').gets.inspect`

Comment: @Stefan I'm not sure how to pull in just the first line. I tried removing everything in the file except for the first line and saving it in a separate file, but I receive the same responses as I do for the full file. I will put it into my question, but it's pretty lengthy.

Comment: `0xFF 0xFE` is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16LE, you should want to try that encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Binary encoding of my file is below:
>
> ```
> "\xFF\xFES\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00s\x00...
> ```

`0xFF` `0xFE` is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16LE.

You have to specify the encoding when processing this file with [`CSV#foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach):

> This method also understands an additional `:encoding` parameter that
>   you can use to specify the Encoding of the data in the file to be
>   read. You must provide this unless your data is in
>   `Encoding::default_external()`. CSV will use this to determine how to
>   parse the data. You may provide a second Encoding to have the data
>   transcoded as it is read. For example, `encoding: "UTF-32BE:UTF-8"`
>   would read UTF-32BE data from the file but transcode it to UTF-8
>   before CSV parses it.

Furthermore you have to specify that a BOM is present. According to the [`IO#new` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding):

> If “BOM|UTF-8”, “BOM|UTF-16LE” or “BOM|UTF16-BE” are (...) present, the BOM is stripped

Applied to your file and example:

```
CSV.foreach(file, col_sep: "\t", encoding: "BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8", headers: true) do |row|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I decoded the OP's pasted binary string and *still* got issues with encoding, plus saw the quotes were incorrect for CSV . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater updated my answer with an example using the OP's data. Note that you have to remove the last character (`\n`) from the data string.

Comment: Thanks for the all the work helping me figure this out. I'm STILL getting an illegal quoting error. The only thing that I can find that is different from your sample of forcing in the binary and my production script that uses the file is the last character (`\n`). I can't really force the binary through sense I'll never manually open this file...Is there anyway to read from this CSV file without manually opening it first?

Comment: Any chance you can upload the file or a portion of it anywhere so I can use read data?

Comment: I've missed a detail, you have to use `encoding: "BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8"`, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems the `file` command is used to give a reasonable-hint to what the file contents are:

```
file /usr/share/dict/words
/usr/share/dict/words: ASCII text

file /usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

If you're on *nix, try running that against your CSV file and see what it says. It's not fool-proof, but it's reasonably accurate.

As something to get you started, here's how to convert space-delimited fields to tab-delimited:

```
row = '"Status"    "Internal ID"   "Language"  "Created At"    "Updated At"    "IP Address"    "Location"  "Username"  "GET Variables" "Referrer"  "Number of Saves"   "Weighted Score"    "Completion Time"   "Invite Code"   "Invite Email"  "Invite Name"   "Invite: branchid"  "Invite: lastname"  "Invite: clientname"    "Invite: membershipid"  "Invite: clientid"  "Invite: dateofbirth"   "Invite: membershiptype"    "Invite: branch"    "Invite: unitid"    "Invite: shortname" "Invite: changedatetime"    "Invite: homephone" "Collector" '
row.gsub!(/"\s+"/, %Q["\t"]) # => "\"Status\"\t\"Internal ID\"\t\"Language\"\t\"Created At\"\t\"Updated At\"\t\"IP Address\"\t\"Location\"\t\"Username\"\t\"GET Variables\"\t\"Referrer\"\t\"Number of Saves\"\t\"Weighted Score\"\t\"Completion Time\"\t\"Invite Code\"\t\"Invite Email\"\t\"Invite Name\"\t\"Invite: branchid\"\t\"Invite: lastname\"\t\"Invite: clientname\"\t\"Invite: membershipid\"\t\"Invite: clientid\"\t\"Invite: dateofbirth\"\t\"Invite: membershiptype\"\t\"Invite: branch\"\t\"I...
```

Comment: The file command returns this:

Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators

So it does appear to be UTF-16LE, but when I pass that into the `:encoding` paramter I get this back:

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-16LE`

How can I use the `gsub` command since I can't open the file?